# Can not set UICollectionView number of items in section from a json response

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, uicollectionview

I'm very new to iOS programming and am trying to set UICollectionView items from a json response.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self downloadJSONData];

    /* uncomment this block to use subclassed cells */
    [self.collectionView registerClass:[CVCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cvCell"];
    /* end of subclass-based cells block */

    // Configure layout
    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    [flowLayout setItemSize:CGSizeMake(150, 150)];
    [flowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
    [self.collectionView setCollectionViewLayout:flowLayout];
    [self.collectionView reloadData];
}

-(void) downloadJSONData {
    NSURL *serviceUrl = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"http://myurlhere.com/"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:serviceUrl];
    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [conn start];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    self.data = [[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)responsedata {
    [self.data appendData:responsedata];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error : %@", error);
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[self.data length]);
    NSString *txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.data encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"response data %@", txt);
    self.dictionaryData = [txt JSONValue];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    //NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:section];
    self.jsonArray = [self.dictionaryData objectForKey:@"images"];
    return [self.jsonArray count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Setup cell identifier
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

    /*  Uncomment this block to use nib-based cells */
    // UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    // [titleLabel setText:cellData];
    /* end of nib-based cell block */

    /* Uncomment this block to use subclass-based cells */
    CVCell *cell = (CVCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *data = [self.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.titleLabel setText:cellData];
    /* end of subclass-based cells block */

    // Return the cell
    return cell;
}
```

When I run the code, it displays nothing. What I want is it displays items and the quantity is equal to the array's count. And one more thing, any suggestion on how to load images asynchronously into the collectionview?

I'm sorry for my english. and I'd be glad if anyone can help me on this.

Thanks. cheers!

Comment: In the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method, add `[self.collectionView reloadData];`.

Comment: _"I'm sorry for my english. and I'd be glad if anyone can help me on this."_ couldn't see anything wrong with your english. You dont have to feel sorry.

Comment: Glad to know that. Could you please accept if it helped. There is a checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: Okay, it says I have to wait for a few minutes to accept the answer. Anyway, any suggestion on how to load the images asynchronously for the items?

Comment: Check this https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage or this https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView. You can also check this sample code http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: Thank you. I'm checking out SDWebImage now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `connectionDidFinishLoading` method add:

```
[self.collectionView reloadData];
```

For Asyn image loading, you can check any of the following,

1. [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)
2. [AsyncImageView](https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView)
3. [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) - It is for UITableView, but you can use the same concept for UICollectionView